# Redirection in PHP is not working Server

Tags: php

Here is My PHP script redirect into admin page. This code working fine in localhost but I will go the server is not redirected.
But Value should be check and validated my only problem was page is not redirected 
I don't know why its happening right now.Any help guys.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
```

Comment: check if it is coming in your if condition,

Comment: Additionally to what Naeem said, I would also recommend turning on error reporting if you haven't all ready and include the errors here. (You can turn error reporting on by pasting in ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); at the top of your page.)

Comment: first check your base_url() to verify its pointing correct location or not.

Comment: What's redirect()? did you define it yourself? Where is this comming from?

Answer (score 0):

In your above code please check if the base_url() returns any value or not.

if redirection is only your aim then can also use php header() function.
Use the below code that i have written

```
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
    header('Location:'.base_url().'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i can check my base_url its correct ...but my page cannot be redirected in admin dashboard ...but localhost it should be working fine ...

Comment: @user2224148, then there is a problem in your redirect function defination, and did you try the code that i have given you in my answer?

Comment: @ Sourabh i check with redirect function its fine ... but i dont know whats actually cause to not redirect in my admin page in my server ...only admin login cant open but validated perfectly , other login pages are working smoothly...

Comment: @user2224148,  can you show the defination of redirect() function so that i can look into it. And is the if(..)  condition returning true at first?

Comment: @ Sourabh Here is my coding : if ($this->config['base_url'] == '')
  {
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
   {
    $base_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $base_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
   }

   else
   {
    $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
   }

   $this->set_item('base_url', $base_url);
  }

Comment: @user2224148, replace url: $base_url = 'localhost/';; with the url of your server

Comment: yeah i replace my server address instead of localhost ...but still also no change !!!

Comment: Here is my JS Login Script it only executed  error: Function setTimeout(function()
    {
     var random_pct = 25 + Math.round(Math.random() * 30);
     
     
     neonLogin.setPercentage(40 + random_pct);
           
     // Send data to the server
     $.ajax({
      url: baseurl + 'index.php?login/ajax_login',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
       email: $("input#email").val(),
       password: $("input#password").val(),
      },
      error: function()
      {
       alert("An error occoured!");
      },

Comment: @user2224148, if you got error in your in js then that means that your intended page did not recieve the ajax request.